# How to identify OBS by color on rtkplot

Tags: layouts, rtklib

I just installed RTKLib latest version ver2.4.3 b34.
When I load rinex observation file(22o), I cannot identify satelite by color.
rinex version is 3.02.

I expected like first picture but reality is second one.
I could not find any option to change from FRQ to OBS

[image]

[image: reality]

Comment: Its nice to ask a clear question in your post and to limit the use of abbreviations to make question easier to understand for others.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+P to open the OPtions window. Then in Plot Style select 'Mark/Line' and hit OK.

[image: PLot Style]